# Special selection jquery Selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a calendar grid (for month). And I want to select period for event. Like at the picture:
Picture 1.
[image]

---

Picture 2.
[image]

How can I implement such a **selection** (when user drag down with the mouse over the cells (8, 15, 22 on picture) he selects all weeks that intersect the cells (picture 2)). 
It seems, JQuery UI selectable plugin doesn't help to make such selection (it would select only 3 cells (8, 15, 22)). Maybe it can or there are other libraries that helps to do that. Maybe It can be fixed with plain js...
 Please, advise something.

Comment: can you share your current code to https://jsfiddle.net/ so we can start from that .. and I think I could help you then

Comment: You could use the `selecting` and `unselecting` events to redraw the ui  while the user is dragging on the cells http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selecting

Answer (score 0):

I made one where you can click and drag. Basically each one gets a unique id then we highlight all the left floated elements between start and end.

```js
mouseDown = null;
from = null;
$("div").each(function (i) {
  $(this).attr("data-id",i);
});
$("div").on("mousedown", function () {
  mouseDown = $(this).attr("data-id");
}).on("mousemove", function () {
  if (mouseDown) {
    mouseUp = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("div").each(function (i) {
      if (i >= mouseDown && i <= mouseUp) {
        $(this).css("background","red");
      }
    });
  }
}).on("mouseup", function (){
  mouseDown = null;
});
```

```css
div {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```